# Basic Angularjs code not running?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I using very simple code. I seem to be missing something that does run the Angularjs code.

here is my html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myAppApp">
<div ng-controller="exempleCtrl">
   HELLO {{name}}!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is app.js code:

```
var app = angular.module('myAppApp',[]);
app.controller('exempleCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

I'm new to Angularjs. So I could be missing something big here.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: can't run script that's not included in the page

Comment: Please check this its working fine  https://plnkr.co/edit/OswC3iek7EuzBdLHUYlZ?p=preview

Comment: you just need to include angular in your script tag,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue, as pointed out in the comments, is that you did not include your Javascript code in the HTML file. So assuming you called it something like `app.js` and is in the same directory as the HTML file, then you need to include it as follows:

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- You should also add reference to angular (use desired version - example here is 1.2.4) -->        
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Here including the app.js-->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myAppApp">
<div ng-controller="exempleCtrl">
   HELLO {{name}}!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Give it a try and let us know if this works.

Comment: This is unlikely to work as well since there is no `<script>` reference to the core Angular library.

Comment: Thanks IshmaelMakitla. the code works perfectly. Thank you Lex.

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer if you found it useful - this will also mark your question as answered so that it does not appear on the questions queue. Happy coding!

Comment: Is there another way to do it without the "<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js">/script>". I mean, can I download the file to local directory and use it?

Comment: Yes - you could download it manually and put it under your app folder - OR (and this I prefer) you could use [bower](https://bower.io/).

Comment: That's what I was using(talking about bower) and faced the issue I was asking about.

Comment: I see, do you perhaps want to post a separate question about those "bower issues"? Community members can then assist you with that as well.